# Getting images off of a Sirona Galileos device

Tags: image, medical

I have been tasked with trying to get to the images created by a Sirona Galileos device  http://www.sirona.com/en/products/imaging-systems/galileos/, and display them on a mobile device. The mobile device part is not the problem, but rather getting to the images stored on this device.

Has anyone on stackoverflow ever developed anything like this before ? 
I really am a bit out of my depth here, any info or comments would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assumption:

- you want to export the dicom data set
- you already can import a dicom data set on your mobile phone

Solution:
Sidexis -> Image -> Export